# Is there any difference between 意志薄弱【いしはくじゃく】, 薄志弱行【はくしじゃっこう】, and 優柔不断【ゆうじゅうふだん】?

Tags: nuances, synonyms, yoji-jukugo

...Because they all seem very similar to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- 意志薄弱: "not strongly determined, easily give up the original goal, easily get bored"
- 薄志弱行: I have never seen this word. Probably very rare/non-standard word.
- 優柔不断: "cannot decide, take long time deciding"